# Core Data - Predicate to-many objects

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a difficult fetch query I don't know how to perform,
My core dat model:

```
Artis
-----
name

songs -> (to-many relationship to Song Object)

Song
-----
title
release_Date

artist -> (to-one relationship to Artist Object)
```

I need a predicate to fetch the 5 top artists with most songs (and at least 2 songs) and all songs release_Date must be in the last 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine:

```
// Predicate for date at least 30 days back

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDate *date30daysBack = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*60*24*30];

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"song.release_date >= %@", date30daysBack];

// Predicate for at least 2 songs

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"songs.@count >= 2"];

// Sort descriptor for most songs

//EDIT
//Sorting should be done after the fetch request.

// Set the fetchLimit of your NSFetchRequest to 5
request.fetchLimit = 5;
```

Comment: Remark: Not every day has 60*60*24 seconds (thing of daylight saving time transitions).

Comment: Correct, the date should be made using `NSDateComponents`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 2 questions: 1. Can I use one predicate with AND to do the first two predicates? 2. Is there a way using predicate or some expression to do the top 5?

Comment: 1. Yes you can, if you want all songs release date to be >= of the date 30 days back use `ALL songs.release_Date >= %@`. 2. No, and this would work only if you have sqlite persistent store.

Comment: hi I think there is a problem with the sort descriptor, it seams that I can't add sort @count to NSFetchRequest. I can do the fetch and than sort, but that won't be so efficient.

Comment: You are right. My mistake. I edited the question. May I ask why sorting would not be efficient after the fetch?

Comment: I would loss some optimizations, for example i can't use fetchLimit.

Comment: That's right. After all don't look at CoreData as a wrapper around SQL.